# Is it possible to achieve different colors for a single text in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to apply different color for my text(single word). For example, please consider the below word,

**"Customer Text"**

In the above word, I need to apply one color to "Customer" and need to apply another color (other than the first text color) to "Text".

Is it achievable in Xamarin.Forms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Label display a FormattedString with letters of different color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056978/how-to-make-a-label-display-a-formattedstring-with-letters-of-different-color)

Comment: Its working in a simple Label.But the same code not working if I load that Label inside a DataTemplate. Any advice?

Comment: Post a new question with your label's `DataTemplate`

Comment: I believe the link to the duplicate question addresses that issue. Look at the 6th comment under the opening question (click "See more" to see all of the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved my requirement by using the way mentioned in the link,
[How to make a Label display a FormattedString with letters of different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056978/how-to-make-a-label-display-a-formattedstring-with-letters-of-different-color)

Answer (score 0):

use the propertychanged event and check if the changed property is text then you can do whatever you want when Text Property change or any property change.