# How do I set a proportional value for row height in a listView so it occupies the entire screen?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, grid, listviewitem

I need the items in my listView to have a height so it the list exactly fits the screen. Here's my code given below. I tried setting the Height of rows in my grid to a custom value, but that would work well, fitting the screen in some devices, while there would be an empty space in other devices due to a different screen size.

```
       <ListView  
              ItemsSource="{Binding PenStocks}"
              ItemSelected="Event_ItemSelected"
              ItemTapped="Event_ItemTapped"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              Margin="5,5,5,0"
              >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="9" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.408*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.051*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.252*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.033*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.153*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.102*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

What can I do for this? Please help me and thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Rewrote this to use a bindablelayout.

View:

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="ParentFlexLayout" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Here we use a bindablelayout - it's very flexible, so you could give it at go and see it it meets your needs

Codebehind:

```
  public ObservableCollection<Color> Colors { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Color>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Colors.Add(Color.Blue);
        Colors.Add(Color.Red);
        Colors.Add(Color.Green);
        Colors.Add(Color.Yellow);
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hello mate, thank you for your response, but in your answer, the first element occupies the entire screen, whereas should it be with all 4 colors displayed on the screen, while the row height being of each color being the same and the collectionView spreading to occupy the screen. So, in my case, what I want is for the collectionView with all elements to fit the entire screen and not just a single element. Thank you!

Comment: Is the amount of rows dynamic?

Comment: See updated answer. Now all elements have the excact size , youll just have to add a gesture for each one if you want them to be selectable.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this fixed my issue! This is a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to your listViewItem to stretch to the height of it's inner control you can use

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
```

It would be better if you share some screen shots.

Or you can check out the below post:

[RowDefinition Height not working when using bound property on Grid in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688621/rowdefinition-height-not-working-when-using-bound-property-on-grid-in-listview)

Comment: hello, i just posted some screenshots, could you please check them........